# compiled view in storage folder is different from the actual view file

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, templating

why are there also views in storage folder in laravel 5? are they compiled views? for some reason i keep getting error when rendering one view: `syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)`. i checked the compiled view, some strange code is added there.

in the actual blade.php file the code is like this(some inline js):

```
<script>
// X1 code {{{
var X1Val;
function Init() {

}
</script>
```

but in the compiled view in the `storage/views/1as234wesdfs...`, theres some strange code:

```
// X1 code <?php echo e(var X1Val;
function X1Init() {
$(function() {

}
```

why is this happening?

Comment: You can run `php artisan clear-compiled` to let laravel create new compiled files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove the "{{{" characters.